# Python utility for parsing blocks?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file that starts something like:

```
databaseCons = {
    main = {
        database = "readable_name",
        hostname = "hostdb1.serv.com",
        instances= {
            slaves = {
                conns = "8"
            }
        }
        maxconns = "5",
        user = "user",
        pass = "pass"
    }
}
```

So, what I'd like to do is parse this out into a `dict` of sub-`dict`s, something like:

`{'main': {'database': 'readable_name', 'hostname': 'hostdb1.serv.com', 'maxconns': '5', 'instances': {'slave': {'maxCount': '8'}}, 'user': 'user', 'pass': 'pass'}}`

I think the above makes sense... but please feel free to edit this if it doesn't. Basically I want the equivalent of:

```
conns = '8'

slave = dict()
slave['maxCount'] = conns

instances = dict()
instances['slave'] = slave

database = 'readable_name'
hostname = 'hostdb1.serv.com'
maxconns = '5'
user = 'user'
pas = 'pass'
main = dict()
main['database'] = database
main['hostname'] = hostname
main['instances'] = instances
main['maxconns'] = maxconns
main['user'] = user
main['pass'] = pas

databaseCons = dict()
databaseCons['main'] = main
```

Are there any modules out there that can handle this sort of parsing? Even what I've suggested above looks messy.. there's got to be a better way I'd imagine.

Comment: Is that language you're using already a thing? If so, what's it called? Did you find any parsers in Python? If not, why are you using it instead of more common things, like JSON for example?

Comment: It's a pre-existing format in our configs -- so the format itself has to remain static unfortunately.

Comment: Why does your output example wrap the dicts in lists?

Comment: Is this a fixed format—as in, even config has the same keys in the same order—or a flexible format where any keys and any level of nesting can occur, like JSON?

Comment: Updated to be more accurate - thanks

Comment: @abarnert - the keys can be in any order, as long as they're properly nested within the correct parent-key

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just replace all equals signs outside of quotation marks with colons, and wrap all keys to the left of colons with quotation marks, and then parse it as json? It's not beautiful, but neither is this format.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an off-the-shelf parser for this language. So you've got a few obvious options. A custom recursive-descent parser shouldn't be that hard, and you can use any of the "JSON in under 100 lines" parsers as a guide, because it's similar in many ways. Or, a recursive-descent transformation to JSON might require less state than a parser, and then you can just drop in `json.loads` or `ijson` as a back end. Or you can describe the grammar and then using a parser library or parser generator (like PyParsing) should be simple.

Comment: @jwilner: "Replace all the equals signs outside of quotation marks" requires at least enough parsing to be able to detect "outside of quotation marks". Especially if the language has some rule for escaping or quoting quotation marks. It's not _hard_, but it's not trivial.

Comment: You could use ``eval("dict(" + ss.replace("{", "dict(").replace("}", ")") + ")")``, where ``ss`` is your data string. Use only if you know, there's no malicious code in your expression.

Comment: Wait, there has to be a comma after the instances block, doesn't there? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Dietrich: Or any braces inside quotes.

Comment: @jwilner: They could be optional before newline, as in YAML… or in Paradox Plaza game files, which this language actually might be a strict subset of, and people have written parsers for that in Python.

Comment: @abarnert, you're of course right, but this might be a more limited use case. It might be enough to say "we don't support escaping quotation marks" because it buys simpler parsing.

Comment: One big question: If "It's a pre-existing format in our configs", doesn't that imply that you already have code that generates and parses this format? What language is that code in? How hard would it be to port to Python? Or just to extract to a .so and call via cffi? (If you _don't_ have any code that can handle this format, then you can't possibly have any files in this format that anyone's actually using, so why can't you just change to another format?)

Comment: I guess my question is then, what is the use case? Is this software where the input files can't be trusted? Is this a script that will be run manually and breakages can be checked? Is this simply a one off? These are questions that should very much be determining how this is approached, although believe me, I love defining a grammar as much as the next guy.

Comment: @Dietrich - your line works, but only if I `print`. `eval` gives a syntax error..

Comment: I tried it on an older version of your post. Here the issues are that there's no comma before the ``maxpass``-line and ``pass`` is a python keyword.

Comment: If you really want to use `eval` (which you really don't), at least use `ast.literal_eval` instead. That eliminates the security hole, and it also means that if you have unexpected data that doesn't fit this pattern, it's more likely to either fail or generate a halfway-decent error message than with `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) parser for your config file:

```
from pyparsing import *

def to_dict(t):
    return {k:v for k,v in t}

series = Forward()
struct = Suppress('{') + series + Suppress('}')
value = quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes) | struct
token = Word(alphanums)
assignment = Group(token + Suppress('=') + value + Suppress(Optional(",")))
series << ZeroOrMore(assignment).setParseAction(to_dict)
language = series + stringEnd

def config_file_to_dict(filename):
    return language.parseFile(filename)[0]

if __name__=="__main__":
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(config_file_to_dict('config.txt'))
```